# PHP - cannot get value from front end form

Tags: javascript, php

I am having an issue getting a value from a front end form and using it in an update query. Front end form populating a select box which is working fine...

```
 echo "<select>";
 while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       echo "<option name='plot' value=\"PlotNumber\">" . 
 $row['PlotNumber'] . "</option>";
 }  
 echo "</select>";
```

Here is the AJAX call:

```
 $('.update').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '../php/update.php',
        success:function(html){
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=html;   
        }  
    });
    return false;
});
```

Here is the php:

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $plot = $_POST['plot'];
    $sql = "UPDATE Developments SET Price = 'BOOKED' WHERE PlotNumber='".$plot."'";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo " records UPDATED successfully";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
```

I'm really stumped as to where im going wrong... Can anyone spot a mistake?

Comment: Your select need to be named plot, not your option.

Comment: here you used .update class in ajax where is define ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Your error is on the select it does not have a name attribute

```
echo "<select>";
 while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       echo "<option name='plot' value=\"PlotNumber\">" . 
 $row['PlotNumber'] . "</option>";
 }  
 echo "</select>";
```

> The above should look like :

```
<?php

echo "<select name=\"plot\">";
 while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       echo "<option value=\"PlotNumber\">" . 
 $row['PlotNumber'] . "</option>";
 }  
 echo "</select>";

 ?>
```

> Then fix your ajax to send data to your php script

```
$('.update').click(function() {
    var FormData = $('#formID').serialize(); 
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '../php/update.php',
        data : FormData,
        success:function(html){
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=html;   
        }  
    });
    return false;
    });
```

> Then after that you need to use prepared statements the correct way

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$plot = $_POST['plot'];
$sql = "UPDATE Developments SET Price = 'BOOKED' WHERE PlotNumber='".$plot."'";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
echo " records UPDATED successfully";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
```

> the above should look like :

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$plot = $_POST['plot'];
$sql = "UPDATE Developments SET Price = 'BOOKED' WHERE PlotNumber= ? ";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$plot]);
echo " records UPDATED successfully";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
 ?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not posting back to the server. I do not get either an error or success message

Comment: update your question with the latest code u have so I can update my answer

Comment: change this `var FormData = $('#formID').serialize();` to `var FormData = $('form').serialize();` @spbrad

Comment: I am now getting a 500 error. in the logs it says that the error is an unexpected [, expecting)... will remove square brackets and retry

Comment: Removed square brackets and I get the success message but it is not actually updating the record...

Comment: change `$stmt->execute([$plot]);` to `$stmt->execute(array($plot));` @spbrad

Comment: Still getting success message but not updating.

Comment: does the plotnumbers on the select option marches the ones on the db?

Comment: I think this `echo "<option value=\"PlotNumber\">" .` should be `echo "<option value=\"$row['PlotNumber']\">" .` @spbrad

Comment: Yes the option values are definitely the correct ones from the database... I have changed from PDO to good old fashioned plain PHP and its working. Must be an issue with the PDO statement

Comment: @spbrad I have found the error change your select option to `echo "<option value=\"".$row['PlotNumber']."\">".$row['PlotNumber'] . "</option>";`

Answer (score 0):

First you have to give name for select tag in HTML:

```
echo "<select  name='plot'>";
 while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       echo "<option value='".$row['PlotNumber']."'>" . 
 $row['PlotNumber'] . "</option>";
 }  
 echo "</select>";
```

you have update your jquery like this.you are not sending any data to your backend.

```
 $('.update').click(function() {
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data:{plot:'$('[name=plot]')'},
        url: '../php/update.php',
        success:function(html){
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=html;   
        }  
    });
    return false;
    });
```